# I want to view a .ps file through Ghostscript 9.05 command prompt

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have a file abc.ps on my desktop. I have installed Ghostscript 9.05 on my machine and I want to view my abc.ps file using the command line.

```
GS>?????
```

What command should I write here. I am working on Windows 7.

Location of exe file: C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.05\bin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Ghostscript documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc):

```
GS> (c:/gs3.53/example.ps)
```

Just looks like you use forward slashes instead of back slashes. For example, if your Windows username is Ankit, you'd enter:

```
GS> (c:/Users/Ankit/Desktop/abc.ps)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit..I am using Ghostscript for the first time.where is the location of example.ps and the steps what exactly needs to be done to open the abc.ps file on my desktop...

Comment: Depends on your Windows username, since it effects the path to your Desktop. I updated the answer assuming the name is Ankit.

Comment: You are looking at a GS prompt, correct? If not, then you need to get Ghostscript started.

Comment: Mind the parentheses, and you have to type `run` to actually run the file.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid the interactive `GS>` commandprompt by running the command like this:

```
gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=display c:/Users/Ankit/Desktop/abc.ps
```

Comment: there is no need for specifying device in this case as 'display' is default device on windows...

Comment: @HABJAN: this is not guaranteed across all versions of Ghostscript. To specify the device you really want takes you always no the save side...

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Ghostview after installing Ghostscript, it is a GUI interface for Ghostscript:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/get50.htm

Note: Be sure you download the same architecture. I.e. if you downloaded and installed 64 bit ghostscript, make sure you also download and install 64 bit Ghostview.